# Remove unwanted characters from all elements in an array

Tags: php, loops, replace, ordinal

I have this function that strips illegal characters and it works fine.

This is the code.

```
<?php

function fix_output($value, $key){
    $new_array = array();
    $newstr = '';
    $good[] = 9;  #tab
    $good[] = 10; #nl
    $good[] = 13; #cr
    for($a=32;$a<127;$a++){
        $good[] = $a;
    }
    $len = strlen($value);
    for($b=0;$b < $len; $b++){
        if(in_array(ord($value[$b]), $good)){
            $newstr .= $value[$b];
        }//fi
    }//rof
    $new_array[$key] = $newstr;
    return $new_array;
}

$array = array();
$array['references1'] = 'Foo1 ◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻';
$array['references2'] = 'Foo2 ◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻';

array_walk($array,"fix_output");

print_r($array);
```

I want to use the PHP function `array_walk` but when I use `print_r($array)` it didn't strip the illegal characters.
What seems to be the problem with this? Any idea would be of help!
Please point out the things that are unclear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_walk` has the option to let you pass the value by reference. This is what you want to do. See the `&` in-front of `$value`:

```
<?php

function fix_output(&$value, $key) {
    $good = array_merge(range(32, 127), [
        9,   // tab
        10,  // nl
        13   // cr
    ]);
    $value = join("", array_map(
        "chr", 
        array_intersect(
            array_map("ord", str_split($value)), 
            $good
        )
    ));
}

$array = array();
$array['references1'] = 'Foo1 ◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻';
$array['references2'] = 'Foo2 ◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻';

array_walk($array,"fix_output");

print_r($array);
```

Now your output is:

```
Array
(
    [references1] => Foo1 
    [references2] => Foo2 
)
```

I changed the implementation to use more of the `array_*` functions so you can see how powerful it can be if you combine them. Also not how you can use `range()` to build the initial *good* array (also check `array_fill_keys`).

Comment: @yowza I added a more compact version at the end

Comment: I appreciate it @michael!

Answer (score 3):

The `array_walk` callback does not return anything, nor does the return value change the value.

If you want to change the value, declare the argument as a reference (`&$value`), and reassign the variable at the end of the callback.

### Working Example:

```
<?php

function fix_output(&$value, $key){
    $newstr = '';
    $good[] = 9;  #tab
    $good[] = 10; #nl
    $good[] = 13; #cr
    for($a=32;$a<127;$a++){
        $good[] = $a;
    }
    $len = strlen($value);
    for($b=0;$b < $len; $b++){
        if(in_array(ord($value[$b]), $good)){
            $newstr .= $value[$b];
        }//fi
    }//rof
    $value = $newstr;
}

$array = array();
$array['references1'] = 'Foo1 ◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻';
$array['references2'] = 'Foo2 ◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻';

array_walk($array,"fix_output");

print_r($array);
```

### Output:

```
Array
(
    [references1] => Foo1
    [references2] => Foo2
)
```

---

Alternately, you could re-factor and use `array_map`, which will create and return a new array.

```
<?php

function fix_output($value){
    $newstr = '';
    $good[] = 9;  #tab
    $good[] = 10; #nl
    $good[] = 13; #cr
    for($a=32;$a<127;$a++){
        $good[] = $a;
    }
    $len = strlen($value);
    for($b=0;$b < $len; $b++){
        if(in_array(ord($value[$b]), $good)){
            $newstr .= $value[$b];
        }//fi
    }//rof
    return $newstr;
}

$array = array();
$array['references1'] = 'Foo1 ◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻';
$array['references2'] = 'Foo2 ◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻';

$new_array = array_map("fix_output", $array);

print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: Also, you can `return $value;` and use `array_map()` instead, to return a new array.

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes, I would go to `array_map()` as well. But the question was `array_walk` in this case.

Comment: This really helped me! I should always double check the manual and look in to every detail.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you don't edit the original array. Pass the first argument into your callback function by reference:

```
function fix_output(&$value, $key){
```

Look at the documentation for array_walk (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php). The point is, that they save the edited value via "&$item1" (function "test_alter" in first example).
I think, if you add a "var_dump($new_array)" at the end of your "fix_output" function, it will show what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your convoluted code is trying to replace every character on the ascii chart between `!` and `~` plus white spaces.  This task easily boils down to a simple `preg_` function call and short regex pattern containing only a negated character class.  No looping is needed because `preg_replace()` will happily iterate an array all by itself.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pU06X))

```
var_export(
    preg_replace('/[^!-~\s]+/', '', $array)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'references1' => 'Foo1 ',
  'references2' => 'Foo2 ',
)
```